# Problem with payment authorizing with Cielo Payment and Google Cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, payment

I'm developing an online shop, I have basically finished my application, at the moment I'm developing the payment part. My app consists on flutter, althought all my payment authorization and configs are stored in google cloud functions for safety reasons. For payments I'm using the Cielo Payment sandbox, with is a payment method that has sandbox so I can make my tests. I'm getting some error from my functions in google cloud with wasn't suppose to happen.
This is the website from cielo so I can acquire the keys for sandbox: https://cadastrosandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/

The error I get:

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'Code' of undefined
```

This is my index.ts:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {CieloConstructor, Cielo,
  TransactionCreditCardRequestModel,
  EnumBrands, CaptureRequestModel} from "cielo";
// CaptureRequestModel, CancelTransactionRequestModel,
// TransactionCreditCardResponseModel

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

const merchantId = functions.config().cielo.merchantid;
const merchantKey = functions.config().cielo.merchantkey;

const cieloParams: CieloConstructor = {
  merchantId: merchantId,
  merchantKey: merchantKey,
  sandbox: true,
  debug: true, // Remover quando for fazer transações reais
};

const cielo = new Cielo(cieloParams);

export const authorizeCreditCard = functions.https.
    onCall( async (data, context) => {
      if (data === null) {
        return {"success": false, "error":
        {"code": -1, "message": "Dados não informados"}};
      }

      if (!context.auth) {
        return {"success": false, "error":
        {"code": -1, "message": "Nenhum usuário logado"}};
      }

      const userId = context.auth.uid;

      const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("users").
          doc(userId).get();
      const userData = snapshot.data() || {};

      console.log("Iniciando autorização");

      let brand: EnumBrands;
      switch (data.creditCard.brand) {
        case "VISA":
          brand = EnumBrands.VISA;
          break;
        case "MASTERCARD":
          brand = EnumBrands.MASTER;
          break;
        case "AMEX":
          brand = EnumBrands.AMEX;
          break;
        case "ELO":
          brand = EnumBrands.ELO;
          break;
        case "JCB":
          brand = EnumBrands.JCB;
          break;
        case "DINERSCLUB":
          brand = EnumBrands.DINERS;
          break;
        case "DISCOVER":
          brand = EnumBrands.DISCOVERY;
          break;
        case "HIPERCARD":
          brand = EnumBrands.HIPERCARD;
          break;
        default:
          return {
            "success": false, "error": {
              "code": -1, "message": "Cartão não suportado: " +
              data.creditCard.brand,
            },
          };
      }

      const saleData: TransactionCreditCardRequestModel = {
        merchantOrderId: data.merchantOrderId,
        customer: {
          name: userData.name,
          identity: data.cpf,
          identityType: "CPF",
          email: userData.email,
          deliveryAddress: {
            street: userData.address.street,
            number: userData.address.number,
            complement: userData.address.complement,
            zipCode: userData.address.zipCode.replace(".", "").replace("-", ""),
            city: userData.address.city,
            state: userData.address.state,
            country: "BRA",
            district: userData.address.district,
          },
        },
        payment: {
          currency: "BRL",
          country: "BRA",
          amount: data.amount,
          installments: data.installments,
          softDescriptor: data.softDescriptor.substring(0, 13),
          type: data.paymentType,
          capture: false,
          creditCard: {
            cardNumber: data.creditCard.cardNumber,
            holder: data.creditCard.holder,
            expirationDate: data.creditCard.expirationDate,
            securityCode: data.creditCard.securityCode,
            brand: brand,
          },
        },
      };

      try {
        const transaction = await cielo.creditCard.transaction(saleData);

        if (transaction.payment.status === 1) {
          return {
            "success": true,
            "paymentId": transaction.payment.paymentId,
          };
        } else {
          let message = "";
          switch (transaction.payment.returnCode) {
            case "5":
              message = "Não Autorizada";
              break;
            case "57":
              message = "Cartão expirado";
              break;
            case "78":
              message = "Cartão bloqueado";
              break;
            case "99":
              message = "Timeout";
              break;
            case "77":
              message = "Cartão cancelado";
              break;
            case "70":
              message = "Problemas com o Cartão de Crédito";
              break;
            default:
              message = transaction.payment.returnMessage;
              break;
          }
          return {
            "success": false,
            "status": transaction.payment.status,
            "error": {
              "code": transaction.payment.returnCode,
              "message": message,
            },
          };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          "success": false,
          "error": {
            "code": error.response[0].Code,
            "message": error.response[0].Message,
          },
        };
      }
    });

export const captureCreditCard = functions.https.
    onCall( async (data, context) => {
      if (data === null) {
        return {"success": false, "error":
        {"code": -1, "message": "Dados não informados"}};
      }

      if (!context.auth) {
        return {"success": false, "error":
        {"code": -1, "message": "Nenhum usuário logado"}};
      }

      const captureParams: CaptureRequestModel = {
        paymentId: data.payId,
      };

      try {
        const capture = await cielo.creditCard.
            captureSaleTransaction(captureParams);

        if (capture.status == 2) {
          return {
            "success": true,
          };
        } else {
          return {
            "success": false,
            "status": capture.status,
            "error": {
              "code": capture.returnCode,
              "message": capture.returnMessage,
            },
          };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          "success": false,
          "error": {
            "code": error.response[0].Code,
            "message": error.response[0].Message,
          },
        };
      }
    });
```

My cielo_payment.dart:

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/credit_card.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user.dart';

class CieloPayment {
  final functions = CloudFunctions.instance;

  Future<String>? authorize(
      {CreditCard? creditCard, num? price, String? orderId, User? user}) async {
    try {
      final Map<String, dynamic> dataSale = {
        'merchantOrderId': orderId,
        'amount': (price! * 100).toInt(),
        'softDescriptor': 'Nnananene',
        'installments': 1,
        'creditCard': creditCard!.toJson(),
        'cpf': user!.cpf,
        'paymentType': 'CreditCard',
      };

      final HttpsCallable callable =
          functions.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'authorizeCreditCard');

      callable.timeout = const Duration(seconds: 60);

      final response = await callable.call(dataSale);
      print(response.data);
      final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data);

      if (data['success'] as bool) {
        return data['paymentId'];
      } else {
        debugPrint('${data['error']['message']}');
        return Future.error(data['error']['message']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('$e');
      return Future.error('Falha ao processar transação. Tente novamente.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> capture(String payId) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> captureData = {'payId': payId};
    final HttpsCallable callable =
        functions.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'captureCreditCard');
    callable.timeout = const Duration(seconds: 60);
    final response = await callable.call(captureData);
    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data as LinkedHashMap);

    if (data['success'] as bool) {
      debugPrint('Captura realizada com sucesso');
    } else {
      debugPrint('${data['error']['message']}');
      return Future.error(data['error']['message']);
    }
  }

  Future<void> cancel(String payId) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> cancelData = {'payId': payId};
    final HttpsCallable callable =
        functions.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'cancelCreditCard');
    callable.timeout = const Duration(seconds: 60);
    final response = await callable.call(cancelData);
    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data as LinkedHashMap);

    if (data['success'] as bool) {
      debugPrint('Cancelamento realizado com sucesso');
    } else {
      debugPrint('${data['error']['message']}');
      return Future.error(data['error']['message']);
    }
  }
}
```

My checkout_manager.dart where everything happens:

```
Future<void> checkout(
      {CreditCard? creditCard,
      Function? onStockFail,
      Function? onSuccess,
      Function? onPayFail}) async {
    loading = true;

    final orderId = await _getOrderId();

    try {
      String? payId = await cieloPayment.authorize(
        creditCard: creditCard,
        price: cartManager!.totalPrice,
        orderId: orderId.toString(),
        user: cartManager!.user,
      );
      debugPrint('success $payId');
    } catch (e) {
      onPayFail!(e);
      loading = false;
      return;
    }

    try {
      await _decrementStock();
    } catch (e) {
      onStockFail!(e);
      loading = false;
      return;
    }
```

[image]
This are the lines the error refers to:

```
line 150:43 -  "code": error.respose[0].Code, // 43 refers to the dot in .Code
line 95:5 -  cardNumber: data.creditCard.cardNumber,
```

This is the error I get from my app, this is not a true credit card, and In the sandbox, when the card finishes with 1, is a successful transaction.
This is the print from dataSale and response:
[image]

After the fix:
[image: Fix]

The error was at the validation from the card expiraation date, with had spaces causing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```js
 error.response[0].Code
 error.response[0].Message
```

to this:

```js
error.code
error.message
```

The correct way to get an error's `code` and `message` in Node.js is by calling [.code](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_code) and [.message](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_message) on the error object itself.

Comment: the error still occurs, I have changed the typo althought

Comment: Is it the same error pointing to line 150 and also did you redeploy the function after the change?

Comment: I did redeploy de functions, and it is poiting to line 150

Comment: Before, it was telling it was `150:38` now it says `150:43` with is the dot from .Code

Comment: It fixed, although I'm getting null as response in my fluter projectg

Comment: In which part exactly are you getting null?

Comment: I have added an print in class CieloPayment, under `final response`. I printed response.data and got `{success: false, error: {code: null, message: null}}`, I have updated the code so you can have a look. I didn't get any firebase errors

Comment: I have added the print from the credit card info too

Comment: The problem, was no the card format, I have added spaces to the expiration date, and the char numbers were wrong, causing an errror

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just `error.Code` and `error.Message` ...according to the API's [documentation](https://developercielo.github.io/en/manual/cielo-ecommerce#integration-errors). There's even a [listing of all possible error codes](https://developercielo.github.io/en/manual/cielo-ecommerce#api-error-codes) available - while Flutter does not matter the least, while the Cloud Function doesn't function properly (until then, Flutter is only adding irrelevant complexity).

Better use [Cloud Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) to log for the Cloud Function... and consider Flutter later on. This is a whole lot more effective than trying to guess what the error may be - and then asking on SO.

For example, to know for certain what is being returned as an error, this would be:

```
functions.logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
```

And once of a sudden, the issue might become quite self-explanatory - and easy to solve.